# Unable to retrieve shot location data from NBA.com, while using C# with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I would like to retrieve shot location datasets from HTML webpages on websites such as NBA.com, CBSsports.com and espn.go.com and then do some data analysis.

My problem is I was unable to retrieve that data I need, while using C# with the help of HTML Agility Pack to do HTML scraping.

First. For example, here is a game tracker on CBS sports between LAL and LAC on April 07, 2013. Link address is,
http://www.cbssports.com/nba/gametracker/live/NBA_20130407_LAL@LAC.

I try to capture x and y coordinates values of those red X points and green O points on court graph.

(sorry about I can not post image here due to limited reputation :( )

Safari web inspector is used to randomly get one of those points. It shows,

```
<div class="homeShot made" playerid="555969" period="1" type="1" ypos="-17" xpos="-1" result="1" time="4:37" distance="25" style="right: 165.53191489361703px; top: 161.6px; "></div>
```

Noticed that the “ypos” and “xpos” in HTML is what I want exactly.

Then I use C# with HTML Agility Pack to retrieve them.

C# code:

```
    string link = "http://www.cbssports.com/nba/gametracker/live/NBA_20130407_LAL@LAC";

    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(link);

    HtmlNodeCollection items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class= 'homeShot made']");

    foreach (HtmlNode item in items) 
    {
        // blablabla
    }
```

But error message in visual studio popped up and told me “items reference is null”.

How can I fix that in a right way?

Second. Another issue is on NBA.com. (sorry about that I can not post second link due to limited reputation)

Similarly, Safari web inspector is used to randomly get one of those red and green points. It shows,

```
<image x="385.12" y="218.3404255319149" width="16" height="16" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="/media/shotchart_legend_o.png"></image>
```

And I noticed it is bounded in a SVG,

```
<svg height="613" version="1.1" width="652" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; ">...</svg>
```

How can I use C# (with or without HTML Agility Pack) to get all of x and y data like “x="385.12" y="218.3404255319149"”?

I appreciate for all of your idea and help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML returned by link you give doesn't have any DIV with CLASS='homeShot made' inside it. If you use a browser to inspect the HTML you're looking at an in-memory representation of the DOM, not the content of the file. The Html Agility Pack only handles raw HTML input, it's not a browser.

If you do a view source, you can confirm that.

So, if the content is built by some javascript code, you must use an embedded browser control, not a static tool such as the Html Agility Pack.